# Como deshabilitar un boton segun el estado de un campo?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenos tardes con todos,
Estoy trabajando una tabla en HTML con PHP en el cual muestra un boton de descarga de pdf pero quiero que el boton se muestre deshabilitado o que no salga si es que el estado de informe no esta 'EMITIDO' adjunto codigo

```
<div class="body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="datos" class="table table-hover js-basic-example dataTable table-custom mb-0">
                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Orden de Servicio</th>
                                            <th>Estacion de Muestreo</th>
                                            <th>Fecha de inicio </th>
                                            <th>Fecha finalizacion</th>
                                            <th>Tipo de muestra</th>
                                            <th>Certificado</th>
                                            <th>Estado informe</th>
                                            <th>Codigo de cliente</th>
                                            <th>Ubicacion</th>
                                            <th>PDF</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>  
                                        <?php foreach ($loginn as $fila): ?>  
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?php echo $fila[0]?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $fila[1]?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $fila[2]?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $fila[3]?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo utf8_encode($fila[4])?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $fila[5]?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $fila[6]?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $fila[7]?></td>
                                                
                                                <td>
                                                 <button class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success "  onclick="window.location.href='scripts/descargar.php?pdf=<?php echo $fila[5]?>'" > PDF </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                     </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes poner una condicion para el renderizado del botón así:

(Suponiendo que el estado del boton está en `$fila[6]`)

```
<td>
    <?php if($fila[6] === "EMITIDO"): ?>
        <button class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success " ...> PDF</button>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

Asi logras que el botón no salga si el estado no es `EMITIDO`

Comment: Muchas gracias! consulta adicional y si quiero agregar un boton que diga aun no disponible, podria poner un else?

Comment: Si, puedes agregar un else con `<?php else: ?>`